# Not getting all possible variables from splitting a web-scraped string

Tags: python

I can't get my program to get every string possible from a split.

Here is one thing I tried:

```
var2 = "apple banana orange"
for var in var2.split():
    #Here I would put what I want to do with the variable, but I put print() to show what happens
    print(var)
```

I got:

```
applebananaorange
```

Full Code:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Charonum/JSCode/main/Files.txt')
responsecontent = str(response.content)
for file in responsecontent.split("\n"):
    file = file.replace("b'", "")
    file = file.replace("'", "")
    file = file.replace(r"\n", "")
    if file == "":
        pass
    else:
        print(file)
        url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Charonum/JSCode/main/code/windows/' + file + ""
        wget.download(url)
```

What should I do?

Comment: You did get every string possible right? You got banana apple and orange. Except the output should have a \n

Comment: I did `print(var + "\n")`, it gives me the same thing but with a next line a the bottom.

Comment: `print()` normally puts each value on a new line. You would only see that if you used `end=''`

Comment: I just tried that, same result as the example on the question

Comment: Sorry, I read that wrong, I wasn't using `end=''`

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/80X06P

Comment: That's strange, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Which version, platform?

Comment: Windows, PyCharm IDE

Comment: I love JetBrains products, but I keep seeing posts where people run things in their console and get screwy output. That's clearly an area that it doesn't do well.

Comment: Well, I am converting something into a string, could that be the problem?

Comment: Then post the full code, otherwise we can't help?

Comment: Okay, I'll edit it.

Comment: CharonProgrammer: always always retest your code in a plain Python session (not under PyCharm IDE) to eliminate the IDE. Also, to eliminate any bugs in PyCharm Python Console, Terminal etc. Also to eliminate PyCharm accidentally running Python 2.x or wrong version.

Comment: Next thing: are you sure `var2 = "apple banana orange"` is the exact string your scraping is returning, and that it doesn't contain e.g. Unicode nonbreaking whitespace characters, which display like spaces but `.split(')` will treat differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like one of the files in the list is not available. It is good practice to always wrap input/output operations with a `try`/`except` to control problems like this. The code below downloads all available files and informs you which files could not be downloaded:

```
import requests
import wget
from urllib.error import HTTPError

response = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Charonum/JSCode/main/Files.txt')
responsecontent = str(response.content)
for file in responsecontent.split("\\n"):
    file = file.replace("b'", "")
    file = file.replace("'", "")
    file = file.replace(r"\n", "")
    if file == "":
        pass
    else:
        url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Charonum/JSCode/main/code/windows/' + file + ""
        print(url)
        try:
            wget.download(url)
        except HTTPError:
            print(f"Error 404: {url} not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for me replacing the `for` statement with this one:

```
for file in responsecontent.split("\\n"):
   ...
```

Comment: It only downloads 2 files. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `responsecontent = str(response.content)` try:

```
responsecontent = response.text
```

and then `for file in responsecontent.split()`.

Comment: That work, but I am using this for downloading files.